# Compiling a Simple C lua5.0 Program, Undefined References

Tags: c, lua, linker-errors, dynamic-linking

I try to Compile this Simple Lua Tutorial Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

    int main (void) {
      char buff[256];
      int error;
      lua_State *L = lua_open();   /* opens Lua */
      luaopen_base(L);             /* opens the basic library */
      luaopen_table(L);            /* opens the table library */
      luaopen_io(L);               /* opens the I/O library */
      luaopen_string(L);           /* opens the string lib. */
      luaopen_math(L);             /* opens the math lib. */

      while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
        error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "line") ||
                lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
        if (error) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
          lua_pop(L, 1);  /* pop error message from the stack */
        }
      }

      lua_close(L);
      return 0;
    }
```

With the Following Command:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/lua50 -L/usr/lib/liblua50.a -llua50 luainterpret.c
```

So the Headers are Linked and Library Binary should also be Linked right?

However i get the following undefined References:

```
/tmp/ccA3kOUt.o: In function `main':
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `lua_open'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `luaopen_base'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `luaopen_table'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `luaopen_io'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `luaopen_string'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `luaopen_math'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `luaL_loadbuffer'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `lua_pcall'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `lua_tostring'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `lua_settop'
luainterpret.c:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `lua_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the /usr/lib/liblua50.a file with nm and the Functions above are indeed there! Why is gcc then not able to find said Functions?
Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the library before the source file (which makes use of the functions present in the library), try putting it afterwards, like

```
gcc -I/usr/include/lua50 -L/usr/lib/liblua50.a  luainterpret.c -llua50
```

From the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

Comment: Yeah that was it! with the following command the Compilation completes:          ```gcc -I/usr/include/lua50 -L/usr/lib/ luainterpret.c -llua50 -llualib50``` Thanks for the Help :)